# Cisco dual routers

Tags: router

I have a business of 300-400 employees. I am looking for a dual router that can push T3 speeds. I have looked into the Cisco RV325 (the router needs to be Cisco) but I'm not sure if that'll be enough for a company of that size. I've also looked at the 2900 series but it seems a little over kill? I'm new to networking and still getting my bearings when it comes to specs. Any help would be appreciated!
The two main requirements right now is that is T3 capable and be a dual router. I will have two IPS connections I want to load balance.

Comment: Have you tried their router selector? http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/assets/prod/routers/cisco-router-selector/index.html

Comment: I have but jargon confuses be after a while. The RV series is the only one that clearly states it's a dual router. Is there another terminology I should be looking for? I called their 800 number but naturally got no help because I was a "Cisco" partner.